# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition using NEWID()

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #TempAnnualOnline
( 
  TrainingStatus nvarchar(70), 
  FirmEmployeeID nvarchar(25), 
  DepartmentID nvarchar(25), 
  StartDate datetime, 
  SectionDate datetime,
  TrainingSessionID uniqueidentifier
) 

INSERT INTO #TempAnnualOnline

select 'Users Not Started' , '1535' , '0100' , '2017-04-17 00:00:00' , NULL , NEWID()
```

I have researched this issue so I don't believe it is a duplicate but please mark it if it is.

On the last item of the select statement, instead of specifying a GUID I have the NEWID() function.

When I run it the way it is, I get this error.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

When I take the TrainingSessionID out of the Table and the NEWID() it works fine.

I am nearly certain I am supplying the right amount of columns to the select.

Is there something about using NEWID() with INSERT INTO SELECT that I am not getting?

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of SQL Server & how/from what are you running this?

Comment: I don't get that error...the query runs fine

Comment: The code you posted runs fine for me. Do you get the error with this script or is it a simplified version of a real query that uses a permanent table. If a permanent table, the error may be due to insert trigger code rather than the query itself.

Comment: Works fine... [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/UMWB61979)

Comment: After closing down Mangement studio and reopening the file, no issues. Very odd. Thanks for verifying that syntax was correct though, greatly appreciated from all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. You have something wrong somewhere else causing this error.

Try to explicitly define your insert columns and see if the issue persists.

```
INSERT INTO #TempAnnualOnline
(TrainingStatus, 
  FirmEmployeeID, 
  DepartmentID, 
  StartDate, 
  SectionDate,
  TrainingSessionID)
select 'Users Not Started' , '1535' , '0100' , '2017-04-17 00:00:00' , NULL , NEWID()
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO #TempAnnualOnline
(TrainingStatus, 
  FirmEmployeeID, 
  DepartmentID, 
  StartDate, 
  SectionDate,
  TrainingSessionID)
Values  ('Users Not Started' , '1535' , '0100' , '2017-04-17 00:00:00' , NULL , NEWID())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why yours doesn't work because it does for me. However if you want to tweak your insert slightly, you can use a SELECT INTO. Added bonus, you don't need to define the temp table columns.

```
SELECT 
    'Users Not Started' AS [TrainingStatus]
    ,'1535' AS FirmEmployeeID
    ,'0100' AS [DepartmentID]
    ,'2017-04-17 00:00:00' AS [StartDate]
    ,NULL AS [SectionDate] 
    ,NEWID() AS [TrainingSessionID]
INTO  #TempAnnualOnline

SELECT * FROM [#TempAnnualOnline]

DROP TABLE #TempAnnualOnline
```

Comment: I just refreshed my environment, closed down Mangament Studio then reopned the script and it's working. Very odd, that being said thank you for this answer. It's a pain having to define the temp table columns upfront. I noticed that the AS clauses don't explicit types. Does SQL then infer the types?

Comment: yeah, and it's going to have problems with that null, it looks like it default it to an INT.

Comment: if you cast the column in a select this method will generate a type in your temp table. For example `select cast('1' as bit) [BitValue] into #TempAnnualOnline` will create a bit column in the temp table

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing SQL Server Management Studio seemed to fix this issue. After closing and reopening the entire thing I ran this exact script with no changes and it worked.

Odd.

I had executed this script a number of times prior to making this modification, dropping and recreating this table each time.

It seemed that there just needed to be a clean slate created.

Thanks to all who verified the script was correct syntax wise.

Also in the future, I will be adapting @AlexanderHiggins, explicitly defining columns upfront just to avoid confusion.